# sequence of tenses in this sentence

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

**1 My husband stayed in Paris and I have gone to New York.**

> (Context: Helen is the wife who has gone to New York. She is talking
> on the phone to Judy and tells her where she and her husband are at
> the moment. Helen's husband is in Paris now. Helen is in New York
> now.)

Do you find the sentence unnatural? I hear that it would be much better to put it this way:

2 My husband stayed in Paris and I went to New York. (however, now it doesn't unequivocally say that I am in New York.)

3 My husband has stayed in Paris and I have gone to New York.

4 I have gone to New York while my husband stayed in Paris.

Could you comment on each sentence nominating one of them as the best one?

Comment: What wuold you like to say ? are you still in New York ? Your husband is in Paris? are you in New York while your Husband is in Paris? Please edit your question

Comment: If the speaker is in New York, I would use _I have come_ rather than _gone_.